# Returning SQL query results as a variable in node.js

Tags: sql, node.js

I'm trying to grab the results of an SQL query in order to use it elsewhere in my code, but I just can't figure out how to get them out. I have nested functions so I tried to get it out through two calls of return, but what comes out isn't valid.

```
var users = getUsers();


function getUsers(req, res){
  dbConnect(req,res);
  return connection.query('SELECT * FROM USERS', function selectAll(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    for (var i in rows) {
        console.log(rows[i]);
    }
    return rows;
    dbClose(req,res);
  })
}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

connection.query is an asynchronous function.

`rows` is only available within the `selectAll` function.  If you'd like to do something with the rows, you need to do it from `selectAll`.

`users` will be undefined because the function `getUsers` itself does not return anything (and can not return rows.

Instead of doing

```
users = get Users();
doSomethingWithUsers(users);
```

do this instead:

```
getUsers();

function getUsers(req, res){
  dbConnect(req,res);
  return connection.query('SELECT * FROM USERS', function selectAll(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    for (var i in rows) {
        console.log(rows[i]);
    }
    doSomethingWithUsers(rows);
    dbClose(req,res);
  })
}
```

Or pass a callback function in getUsers that gets passed the result.

Comment: I tried setting var users = rows from within selectAll, but that didn't work either

Comment: because the code within selectAll executes later, after the results have come back, not right after getUsers() returns to you.